Application crashing, and dotnet framework runtime level showing The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception
Environment : OS Microsoft Windows Server 2019
Dotnet framework: 4.7
SQL : SQL Server 2019
Note: Previously our application was working fine in 2016 OS. Once we upgraded to OS 2019 we are facing below issue
Application level - Event viewer log
Faulting application name: XXXX.exe, version: XXXX, time stamp: 0x66338cfc
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.17763.5458, time stamp: 0x761f6403
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00056007
Faulting process id: 0x3a9c
Faulting application start time: 0x01daa07dba30b473
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 41b0c901-aa9f-460b-a492-487d8ccd1b58
Faulting package full name:
Dotnet run time Level - Event Viewer log
Application: XXXX.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 77D26007
Stack:
We are using some Avaya dlls(C#) in our CPP code.
while adding the devices in the conference. application is crashed.

Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656210/application-crash-in-ntdll-dll-version-6-1-7601-23677-with-net-framework-vers?rq=2 but not possible to diagnose by us. You need to take the crash dump and open that in VS or windbg and examine where and how the app crashed.

In order to diagnose the problem, or to suggest a solution, we would need to see some of the C++ code that is consuming the .NET DLL. Getting a reliable callstack would also help, at a minimum to identify which piece of the code is a problem. Is the C++ managed or unmanaged/.
